# Truth table for $p \implies q$

Tags: logic

I didnt understand the truth table for $p \implies q$ (where $p$ and $q$ are statements). Can someone please explain it to me?

It would be better if someone explains with an example.

Comment: Where is the truth table? What are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: The table should represent "if $p$ then $q$". So every entry in the table is $true$, except for the case of $[p=true]\wedge[q=false]$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not understand *why* the truth table is as it is. Recall the truth table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\rightarrow Q \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}$$
Where $1$ represents True, and $0$ represents False.

The first two lines follow naturally from the "intuitive English language definition", that is $$\text{If }P\text{, Then }Q.$$
So if $P$ holds, and $Q$ holds then the statement $\text{If }P\text{, Then }Q$ is true; if $Q$ did not hold, it would be false.

As for the bottom two lines, we're asking $\text{If }P\text{, Then }Q$ when $P$ is always false. Another way to read this would be $$\text{Whenever }P\text{ is true, Then }Q\text{ is necessarily true.}$$

But if $P$ is not true, this is vacuously true. For example, if $P$ were "There are 25 hours in this day", and $Q$ were "It is sunny today", then we're asking "Whenever there are 25 hours in the day, it is sunny". Well there are never 25 hours in the day, so this is true. *Every* time there is 25 hours in the day, *it is* sunny.

See [Vacuous truth on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for further reading. There are more examples here.

Comment: You should explain that you used $1$ and $0$ for "true" and "false", respectively.

Comment: @GEdgar clarified, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle these types of questions is to ask yourself for every possible combination of the truth values of p and q, "Is q at least as true as p?" If yes, then p -> q is true, if no, then p -> q is false.